# Moments of random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a positive random variable with $\mathbb{E}[X^{r}]<+\infty$,   $0<r<1$.

Is it true that also $\mathbb{E}[X^{r-1}]<+\infty$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be true to me (but I am not sure):

For instance, for $0<\varepsilon<1$ let $X$ be the following distribution:

for $n\in\mathbb N$, $X=1/n$ with proba $C/n^{1+\varepsilon}$ (where $C=\zeta(1+\varepsilon)^{-1}$ is the normalizing factor)

Then it seems that $\mathbb E[X^r]<\infty$ for all $0<r<1$ but $\mathbb E[X^{r-1}]=\infty$ for all $r\leq 1-\varepsilon$.

Comment: You're right! Just made a numerical proof with r=1/2 and epsilon=1/3.

Comment: Do you think it is true also for absolutely continuous random variables?